# Сумма элементов ряда двумерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Полное задание - Создать матрицу размером 5 х 5 с помощью генератора целых Как сделать без такого кол-ва if-ов? Спасибо числа, вывести ее на экран. Найти сумму элементов в строках, которые содержат только положительные числа.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 5;

    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int sum_first = 0, sum_second = 0, sum_third = 0, sum_fourth = 0, sum_fifth = 0;
    

    //srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 21 - 5;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++)
    {
        if (arr[0][k] > 0)
            sum_first += arr[0][k];
        else if (arr[0][k] <= 0)
        {
            sum_first = 0;
            break;
        }

        if (arr[1][k] > 0)
            sum_second += arr[1][k];
        else if (arr[1][k] <= 0)
        {
            sum_second = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << sum_first << endl;
    cout << sum_second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Будь ласка, пишіть російською тут. Або англійською пишіть в англійському варіанті сайту. Якщо потрібно, використовуйте Google Translate (як я зараз:-).

Comment: Добре, дякую !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, [так](https://ideone.com/qr7bGP):

```
int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 5;

    int arr[ROWS][COLS];

    int sum[ROWS][2]{};
    //srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << (arr[i][j] = rand() % 21 - 5) << "\t";
            sum[i][0] += arr[i][j];
            if (arr[i][j] < 0) sum[i][1] = 1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        cout << "Row " << i << ": ";
        if (sum[i][1])
            cout << "has negative numbers\n";
        else
            cout << "sum = " << sum[i][0] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, код рабоатет. ) Что значит int sum[ROWS][2]{}; if (arr[i][j] < 0) sum[i][1] = 1;

Comment: Да я знаю, что работает... Про 1 - я просто смотрю, есть ли в строке отрицательное число. Если есть - выставляю 1, значит, для этой строки сумму не выводить...

Comment: Спасибо большое